# Is there a way to find the file path for a texture on a PyCollada geometry?

Tags: python, geometry, textures, collada

The problem I am trying to solve is I have a model I created in blender with several separate geometries, each with their own texture file.

From what I understand, you can create a mesh in PyCollada and get the texture coordinates like so:

```
from collada import Collada

mesh = Collada("my_model.dae")

geometries = [g for g in mesh.geometries] # gets a list of the geometries
tex_paths = [im.path for im in mesh.images] # gets a list of the texture paths
```

However, the problem I am running in to is the texture paths and the geometries do not share an index, and I can't seem to find an abstracted way to consistently map a geometry to its diffuse texture file. Any tips on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, and this is how i did it:

```
rel_path = "../../../"
tex_paths = []

# iterate over geometries in the mesh
for geom in mesh.geometries:
    abs_path = mesh.materials[geom.primitives[0].material].effect.params[0].image.path
    tex_paths.append(rel_path + abs_path)
```

where rel_path is just the path relative to the python script where the model and textures exist.